I dont know how to remove the blue highlight rectangle when i type from blockman VS code extension
I can't find an option to remove this blue square that highlights the line I'm actually typing in. How do I remove it? Anybody knows?
I have been looking for an answer to my problem in Google and also  looking in the main blockman use guide, but I couldn't find a solution.


find the theme colors for that and set them to transparent in your setings, or search settings to disable line highlight

Just found the solution. Thank you! :D
